# Ember-Table with Fixture Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, fixtures, ember-table

I am trying to load an ember table using Ember-Data and Fixtures. I can see the rows generated in the table , however they are empty. Note that it does generate the correct number of rows, it just does not show data. If  I use an array instead, everything works properly. Also, if I remove the table and just do {{#each}}, data shows just fine too.
Any ideas would be welcome!
Thanks

here is the html:

```
    <div class="table-container">
        {{table-component
        hasFooter=false
        columnsBinding="columns"
        contentBinding="content"}}
    </div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
App.CustomersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    numRows: 1,
    columns: function() {
    var nameColumn, typeColumn, phoneColumn, identifierColumn;
    nameColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
        columnWidth: 150,
        textAlign: 'text-align-left',
        headerCellName: 'Name',
        getCellContent: function (row) {
            return row.name;
        }

    });
    typeColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
        columnWidth: 150,
        textAlign: 'text-align-left',
        headerCellName: 'Type',
        getCellContent: function (row) {
            return row.type;
        }

    });
    phoneColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
        columnWidth: 100,
        textAlign: 'text-align-left',
        headerCellName: 'Phone',
        getCellContent: function (row) {
            return row.phone;
        }

    });
    identifierColumn = Ember.Table.ColumnDefinition.create({
        columnWidth: 150,
        textAlign: 'text-align-left',
        headerCellName: 'ID',
        getCellContent: function (row) {
            return row.identifier;
        }

    });
    console.log('in columns func');
    console.log(this.get('content'));
    return [nameColumn, typeColumn, phoneColumn, identifierColumn];
}.property(),

content: function() {
    /*var temp= [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Seller',
            type: 'Supermarket',
            phone: '1-800-Sell',
            identifier: '12345'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Sell',
            type: 'Supermarket',
            phone: '1-800-Sell2',
            identifier: '12356'
        }];
    return temp;*/

return this.store.toArray
    }.property('numRows')
});
```

(note the commented array that works is also included above)

And the model:

```
App.Customers = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
type: DS.attr('string'),
phone: DS.attr('string'),
identifier: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an array, the objects are turned into real objects as opposed to being Ember.Object. You should be able to use:

```
getCellContent: function (row) {
  return row.get('name');
}
```

To select the data on each row properly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! so, would I use that instead of the content property? or use that to populate an array inside the content property?

Comment: In this case `row` is actually being called for each row in your content. So you do have to still provide content but if your content is ember objects you'll need to use the `get` function on each of those.